# Histogram with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, diagrams

I am a newbie in TeX. And I need to use Tikz to make a copy of this histogram

[image]

Of course, I am able to make something similar. Unfortunately, I need a replica (90%) of it. Can anybody help me?

What I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={excellent, good, average, bad, awful},
        ylabel = {probability},
        xlabel = {Quality},
    xtick=data]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=white] coordinates {
        (excellent,5)
        (good,10)
        (average,50)
    (bad, 20)
    (awful,15)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you include the part that you already have?

Comment: Looking at »[pgfplots](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots)« would be a good start.

Comment: @countzero The usual way of writing is “TikZ” rather than “Tikz”

Comment: to get started: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8582/basic-bar-chart-with-text-as-x-axis-labels

Comment: I've included the part that I have.

Comment: Solution: [don't use a histogram](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/51753/27923).

Comment: @Dmitry Sorry to bother you, but I just noticed that although you have up-voted answers to your questions, you still haven't accepted any (accepting and up-voting are two different actions). Please revisit your questions accepting the answer that you consider best solved your problems, by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Answer (score 29):

Perhaps something like this.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      bar width=20pt,
      xlabel={Quality},
      ylabel={Probability},
      ymin=0,
      ytick=\empty,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={excellent,good,average,bad,awful},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
    ]
      \addplot[fill=white] coordinates {
        (excellent,5)
        (good,10)
        (average,50)
        (bad,20)
        (awful,15)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 15):

Here are a collection of settings that would fix tiny details. You can comment them out to see what they are doing. The arrow heads are from  [DIN conform arrowheads and hatching in TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52786/din-conform-arrowheads-and-hatching-in-tikz)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52786/din-conform-arrowheads-and-hatching-in-tikz
\pgfarrowsdeclare{DIN}{DIN}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.25\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=7.29\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by.5\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsleftextend{+-\pgfutil@tempdimb}
  \pgfutil@tempdimb=.5\pgfutil@tempdima\advance\pgfutil@tempdimb by1.6\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfarrowsrightextend{+\pgfutil@tempdimb}
}
{
  \pgfutil@tempdima=0.5pt%
  \advance\pgfutil@tempdima by.25\pgflinewidth%
  \pgfsetdash{}{+0pt}
  \pgfsetmiterjoin
  \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{-4mm}{0.5mm}}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0\pgfutil@tempdima}}
  \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointadd{\pgfqpoint{0.5\pgfutil@tempdima}{0pt}}{\pgfqpoint{-4mm}{-0.5mm}}}
  \pgfpathclose
  \pgfusepathqfillstroke
}
\pgfarrowsdeclarereversed{DIN reversed}{DIN reversed}{DIN}{DIN}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    symbolic x coords={excellent, good, average, bad, awful},
        ylabel = {probability},
        xlabel = {Quality},
        ytick=\empty,ymin=0,
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=left,
        enlarge x limits=0.2,
        axis line style={-DIN,ultra thin},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%},
        ylabel near ticks,
        xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-3mm},
        xtick style={draw=none},
        every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.south east)},anchor=north west}
    ]
    \addplot[ybar,fill=white] coordinates {
        (excellent,5)
        (good,10)
        (average,50)
    (bad, 20)
    (awful,15)
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Dmitry The polite way to thank people on TeX.SE is to accept the answer that satisfies you, and vote it up. You can vote up more than one answer if several are helpful.

Comment: @EthanBolker I think it's OK to express joy and appreciation for the help one receives :)

Comment: @tommy.carstensen Why not joy and enthusiasm AND a check and an upvote?

Comment: @percusse How can I set up the width and height of the whole histogram?

Comment: @Matthias You can use the `width` and `height` keys. If you use only one of those keys, the other one is changed according to the aspect ratio of the box. You need to give both of them to change the aspect ratio,

Comment: @percusse Thx. Is it also possible to give the `width` in relative to the page wdith or something like this. As one can do it with including Images? I feel uncomfortable to do this in `pt`..

Comment: @Matthias Sure you can always use `width = .8\textwidth` and so on.