# Adding a Legend to a Histogram

Tags: pgfplots, legend, histogram

I created the following histogram but all labels were messed up.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      bar width=20pt,
      ymin=0,
      %ymax=100,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={First Variable, Second Variable, Third Variable, Fourth Variable, Fifth Variable},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
    ]

      \addplot[fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1] coordinates {
        (First Variable,42)
        (Second Variable,36)
        (Third Variable,23)
        (Fourth Variable,22)
        (Fifth Variable,61)
      };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Then I shortened the labels to fit them well but it required me to add the legend. But the legend is just giving one label, not others. I need help regarding either fitting the labels or explaining the labels in the legend.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      ybar,
      bar width=20pt,
      ymin=0,
      %ymax=100,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={A, B, C, D, E},
      xticklabel style={anchor=base,yshift=-\baselineskip},
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
    ]

      \addplot[fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1] coordinates {
        (A,42)
        (B,36)
        (C,23)
        (D,22)
        (E,61)
      };
\legend{A=First Variable, B=Second Variable, C=Third Variable, D=Fourth Variable,E=Fifth Variable}
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/histogram-with-tikz/123867#123867 as a starting point.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Histogram with Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/histogram-with-tikz)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may not need to shorten the labels. If you add `text width=1.3cm` to the `xticklabel style` the labels will break across multiple lines. If you also make the diagram a bit wider by setting `width`, there is more room. The exact lengths used will depend on your specific case, so adjust the `width` and `text width` settings as you see fit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{
  compat=newest,
  xlabel near ticks,
  ylabel near ticks
}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
    \begin{axis}[
      width=10cm, % increase width of diagram a bit
      height=6cm,
      ybar,
      bar width=20pt,
      ymin=0,
      %ymax=100,
      xtick=data,
      axis x line=bottom,
      axis y line=left,
      enlarge x limits=0.2,
      symbolic x coords={First Variable, Second Variable, Third Variable, Fourth Variable, Fifth Variable},
      xticklabel style={
         anchor=base,
         yshift=-\baselineskip,
         text width=1.3cm, % means longer labels will be broken across multiple lines
         align=center, % center align
         % font=\scriptsize % if necessary, you could reduce the font size further
      },
      nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfplotspointmeta\%}
    ]

      \addplot[fill=orange,fill opacity=0.5, text opacity=1] coordinates {
        (First Variable,42)
        (Second Variable,36)
        (Third Variable,23)
        (Fourth Variable,22)
        (Fifth Variable,61)
      };
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: To improve on that, maybe adding abbreviations? e.g. First Variable: v1.