# References for making histograms

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to produce a histogram as similar to the following as possible.

[image]

The histogram itself is not too structured, so I guess it shouldn't be too hard a task, but I am kind of struggling to find some standard references on the subject.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Did you search on the site for [histogram](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123866/histogram-with-tikz)? Plus, your question is pretty vague. What do you want exactly? Is colouring only one bar your issue? Is it naming the horizontal axis?... Please be more precise and add a Minimal Working Example of what you tried yet.

Comment: There are plenty of ways how to produce this graph. But a lot depends on how the **data** are available, i.e. if the histogram data are already available or if the histogram data first have to be "computed" from a list. In the first case this is -- besides the special coloring of some bars -- a standard [tag:bar-chart] where you find plenty of examples here on TeX.SX. So please have a look and provide an MWE that allows us to help you.

Comment: For example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/128028/bar-chart-single-colored-bar or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58548/is-it-possible-to-change-the-color-of-a-single-bar-when-the-bar-plot-is-based-on, just with `ybar` instead of `xbar`, might be a start.