# How to deal in pgfplots with repeated symbolic coords using data from a file

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to generate a series of industrial plots resulting from a DoE, according to the example of the MWE, but I cannot find a way to generate it directly from a `.csv` file or `\datatable`, since the `xticks` gets duplicated for each occurence found in the `.csv` file. Is there a way to force all datapoints sharing the same symbolic xcoord to be aligned vertically, as in the example?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=4cm, height =8cm}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
title= {Fatigue test results.},
 only marks, mark size=0.5mm, enlarge x limits=0.3,
   xlabel={Configuration},ylabel={Cycles before failure}, 
   symbolic x coords={A,C}, xtick={A,C}]
\addplot coordinates {(A,1362)(A,2840) (A,687) (A,2771)};
\addplot coordinates {(C,2130)(C,3544) (C,1844)(C,3447)}; 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{filecontents}{data1.csv}
config;cycles 
A;1362
A;2840
A;687
A;2771
C;2130
C;3544
C;1844
C;3447
\end{filecontents}{data1.csv}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data1.csv}{\datatableone}


% what code could lead to the same plot, using the file or the datatable ?
% see below

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[ 
    xtick=data,
    title= {Fatigue test results.},
     only marks, mark size=0.5mm, enlarge x limits=0.3,
       xlabel={Configuration},ylabel={Cycles before failure}, 
       symbolic x coords={A,C}]
    \addplot table [x= config, y=cycles] \datatableone;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I tried to find some solution but that does seem to be a problem fit to my knowledge. Though I've found a couple interesting threads you should check: [String column tick labels and plotting selected samples on y axis with groupplots?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/182777/string-column-tick-labels-and-plotting-selected-samples-on-y-axis-with-groupplot) and [pgfplots using strings *from data table* as x axis labels in bar chart](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63335/pgfplots-using-strings-from-data-table-as-x-axis-labels-in-bar-chart)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you where searching for something like this ...

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        width=4cm,
        height=8cm,
        %
        % put all common keys in a style
        my style/.style={
            title={Fatigue test results.},
            only marks,
            mark size=0.5mm,
            enlarge x limits=0.3,
            xlabel={Configuration},
            ylabel={Cycles before failure},
            symbolic x coords={A,C},
        },
    }
\usepackage{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{data1.csv}
        config;cycles
        A;1362
        A;2840
        A;687
        A;2771
        C;2130
        C;3544
        C;1844
        C;3447
    \end{filecontents}{data1.csv}
    \pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data1.csv}{\datatableone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % load the style
            my style,
            xtick={A,C},
        ]
            \addplot coordinates {(A,1362)(A,2840) (A,687) (A,2771)};
            \addplot coordinates {(C,2130)(C,3544) (C,1844)(C,3447)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}

    % what code could lead to the same plot, using the file or the datatable ?
    % see below
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            % load the style
            my style,
            xtick=data,
        ]
            \addplot [
                % define scatter classes so they match the previous plot
                scatter/classes={
                    A={mark=*,blue},
                    C={mark=square*,red}
                },
                % use scatter plot and set the source to `explicit symbolic'
                scatter,
                scatter src=explicit symbolic,
            ] table [
                x=config,y=cycles,meta=config] \datatableone;
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and added it to the code.